# My NSSavePanel is not saving the file. (OSX 10.5)

Tags: cocoa

My NSSavePanel is not saving the file. I'm building an app for **OSX 10.5**

```
NSSavePanel *createPanel = [[NSSavePanel alloc] init];  
    [createPanel setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    int result = [createPanel runModal];
    if (result == 1) {
        [lyricsFileField setStringValue:[createPanel filename]];
    }
```

I manually type the file name and I select the directory but the file is not saved.

Thanks

ps. How do I pass a file path to the panel ? (setNameFieldStringValue: is for > 10.6 only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving any file, You just change text in Your textField to Your location string. If You want to save the file You need to use this:

```
[data writeToFile:[createPanel filename] atomically: NO];
```

instead:

```
[lyricsFileField setStringValue:[createPanel filename]];
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can pass the file path to the panel ?

Comment: If You want to set path to file You can use [createPanel setDirectoryURL:NSURL]; write this after -setCanCreateDirectories.

Answer (score 1):

`NSSavePanel` is not supposed to save file, it is for selecting the file, for what I know.

And there's a `directory` and `filename` properties or some such prior to 10.6.

Comment: I can't find the equivalent of setNameFieldStringValue for OSX < 10.6

Comment: Is it not the `filename` or the combination of `filename` and `directory` properties?

Comment: ah, I thought they have setters. Maybe this one will be of help: `- (NSInteger)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path file:(NSString *)filename` ?